# How do I add an account with permissions to the entirety of the subdirectory structure and all files contained therein?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, ownership, windows.old

Bricked my system. Recovered it. Trying to move the windows.old folder (move, not delete) from the system drive so I can pick it apart later.

Permissions problems. Because of course.

Added the new account(s) through the security tab -

[image: Permissions Set]

Changed the owner of the entire folder -

[image]

Still getting this $#!+ -

[image]

I now understand the importance of the MCVE - As I was dropping the second screenshot, I noticed the empty checkbox next to 'Replace all child object permission entries from object'.

For the benefit of the next person, I am still going to post this question and then answer it with the obvious solution - a step by step for the next poor bastard who bricks his system.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Step By Step - To Change Permissions of the directory and all of its contents:**

1: Open Explorer.

2: Browse to the directory in question.

3: Right-Click Offending folder.

4: Click Properties

5: Click Security Tab

6: Click Advanced

7: Below the 'Permission Entries' box, click 'Add'

8: At the top of the new window, click 'Select a principal'

9: Type the local account name, or the email address of the relevant Microsoft Account, into the field below 'Enter the object name to select'.

9a: Click 'Check Names' and confirm what appears in that field matches the account name in question.

10: Click 'OK'.

11: Check the relevant boxes under Basic Permissions. Also, click 'Show Advanced Permissions' and check the additional relevant boxes.

11a: **Do NOT think that ticking the 'Take Ownership' advanced permissions checkbox will propagate ownership of the directory and all of its files and subdirectories. I just tested this while writing this answer. It will not.**

12: Click 'OK'.

13: **Click the Check Box at the bottom of the window next to 'Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object (This is the step I missed which led to much wringing of hands and gnashing of teeth).**

14: Click 'Apply'. Click 'Yes' in the scary pop-up window that asks if you're sure, and wait. Depending on how dense the contents of the folder, you may be waiting a few minutes. Don't worry about if this f***s up permissions for other users, you can always go back and add the permissions of those other users later. Chances are it won't unless you removed them all from the parent directory, and chances are you're the only person using this computer anyway.

15: You're done. Congratulations. Move the folder, delete it, rename it, burn your house down for insurance money and use that money to get wasted celebrating, but probably not that last one.

**To take ownership of the directory and every directory within.**

1: Follow steps 1-6 as indicated above.

2: Click 'Change' next to the name of the current owner.

3: Follow steps 9-10 as indicated above.

4: Click the check-box underneath the new owner name next to 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects'.

5. Click 'Apply' and wait. Congratulations. All those folders and files are belong to whomever.

This is probably a horse so dead that its entire lineage is dust by this point, but here's hoping this helps someone, somewhere, sometime.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and *safest* thing to do is to make a compete *disk image*, using a tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [any reliable alternative.](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). This will eliminate the worry that something you do whilst reviving Windows might damage or delete that folder *or others*. Changing permissions on working folders can sometimes introduce more issues into Windows OS.

Then to access *any* folder, just mount the disk image as if it were a drive. In *Reflect*, for example, under the *Restore* menu, choose *Explore image*, and check *Enable access to restricted folders*.

[image: Browse Restricted Folders]

You can safely browse *any* folder of the image, open any files, and copy folders and their contents without affecting Windows OS. When done, *Detach* the partition and eject the drive with the image.

Comment: That's neat but your plug is saying exactly this: 'Here's a hindsight solution to your very real in the now problem'. Sort of outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Will,it is **not too late** to make a disk image! you stated you've recovered the system, so the data is on the disk. Save it before you play with permissions!

Comment: It's all good. I only moved the windows.old folder. That's all I needed to touch. Everything else is good. But thanks for the tip. I'll look into the program for any of my future system un-bricking needs.

Answer (score 0):

When you take owner, make sure you also select [v] Replace child object permissions with inherited permissions. Once you are owner on all folders, close all windows, go back into properties to the security tab, and do the same for security permissions (so tick the [v] Replace child object permissions with inherited permissions.)

If that doesn't work, go up one folder and do it there. This is the way to do it, and it will work.